# facet.date.gap=+1MILLISECOND is not working?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using the latest version of solr and I am working on project where 1 millisecond also cost's. In oder to maintain some probablity I want to give date range in milliseconds.

```
facet.date=dateField
facet.date.start=2015-12-21T12:29:03.991Z
facet.date.end=2015-12-21T12:29:03.999Z
facet.date.gap=+1MILLISECOND
```

the above shown example is not working can anyone help me in that issue.

Comment: Date faceting using the type specific `facet.date` parameters has been deprecated since Solr 3.1. -> try `facet.range`

Comment: Thanx karsten R. it worked